# I can't figure out how to use react-navigation in a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am having the worst time trying to figure out how to use react-navigation in a doubly-nested child component.  I have tried using callback functions and passing navigation as props, but I can't figure it out.  Would someone mind taking a look?

I have tried using callbacks and also passing navigation in as props.  I am getting a lot of errors like "can't find props, can't find navigation etc."  Help is greatly appreciated.

```
//main function (App.js)

import React from 'react';
import Bar from "./Bar"
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, SafeAreaView, Dimensions, Button } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator, StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';


function HomeScreen() {


  return (
      <View>
        <Bar navigation = {this.navigation}/>
      </View>



  );
}


function DetailsScreen() {
  return (
    <Text>Hello from Details screen</Text>
  )
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
  },
  Details: {
    screen: DetailsScreen,
  },
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);


//First Child Component

import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Image, StyleSheet, View, Text,Dimensions
} from "react-native";
import Animated from "react-native-reanimated";
import BarButton from "./BarButton"

export default class Bar extends Component {
  bottombarcallback3 = () => this.props.scopeSpecificFunction23();
render() {
  return (
    <View style ={{
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      backgroundColor: "#C0C0C0",
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
    }}>
      <BarButton navigation = {this.navigation} />
    </View>
  )
}
}

//final child component


import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Image, StyleSheet, View, Text,Dimensions, Button
} from "react-native";
import Animated from "react-native-reanimated";
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator, StackActions, NavigationActions, withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

export default class BarButton extends Component {
render() {
  return (
    <View style = {{
      width: 80,
      height: 80,
      backgroundColor: "#DC143C",
    }}>
    <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('Like')}}
      />
    </View>
  )
}
}
```

I just want to be able to change screens from a child component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `react-navigation` they provide a [higher order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) that allows you to access the navigation from anywhere inside the tree, though still lower than the navigation provider (StackNavigatior, TabNavigator, etc.). You can modify your lower component to look like this:

```
// Extra code omitted 

import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation';

class BarButton extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('Like')}}
       />
    )
  }
}

export default withNavigation(BarButton)
```

If you need to know if the component is focused or not, you can use `withNavigationFocus` in the exact same manor. This higher order component injects `navigation` into your props so you can use it without prop drilling.

Here is the documentation for `withNavigation` https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html and `withNavigationFocus`: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation-focus.html

Comment: Thanks!  I'm looking at it rn and if I can figure it out I'll definitely mark it as accepted.  Thanks again!!